# 3:13 error Require statement not part of import statement @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

Tags: javascript, git, git-push

I faced this error " 3:13  error  Require statement not part of import statement  @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires" while pushing repository to github

`const Koa = require("koa");`
I imported this in line 3

I tried to search, but I didn't find any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:
With Typescript, use have to use ES6 Syntax instead of require. So to include Koa you need to write

```
import Koa from 'koa';
```

Option 2:
You can disable this rule by editing .eslintrc.js

```
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Haziks suggestion, you also have the option to turn off this eslint rule in the file you need instead of disabling the rule everywhere by adding this to the start of said file

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
```

or for a specific line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
```